# Openconnect + Docker - No internet connection on VPN connection

Tags: linux, docker

I've been using Openconnect with Docker to create a container that will allow access to an external database for development. However, as soon as I connect via the Openconnect VPN, I can't appear to connect to anything.

Before I connect to the VPN:

```
    root@932386ed6d5f:/# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                   
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                 
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                 
Reading package lists... Done                     
root@932386ed6d5f:/#
```

After I connect to the VPN:

```
root@932386ed6d5f:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                    
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                          
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                          
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
0% [Working]^C
```

Command that is being run:

```
    openconnect -b --no-dtls --servercert sha256:CENSORED --user=USER -q IP --passwd-on-stdin < pass.txt
```

Response from the command:

```
GROUP: [VPNGROUP]:VPNGROUP
```

I can ping the IP I need from the VPN fine. However, anything outside the container does not work. I am using the Docker run command to debug the image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

LABEL maintainer="connorbrady@codox.eu"

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV DOMAIN=SSL_DOMAIN

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nginx \
    wget \
    php7.2 \
    php7.2-cli \
    php7.2-curl \
    php7.2-fpm \
    php7.2-gd \
    php7.2-intl \
    php7.2-json \
    php7.2-mbstring \
    php7.2-mysql \
    php7.2-opcache \
    php7.2-xml \
    php7.2-zip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


# Composer
RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/download/1.9.1/composer.phar
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# TODO - Move to top
RUN add-apt-repository main
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN add-apt-repository restricted
RUN add-apt-repository multiverse
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install openconnect vpnc nano glances iputils-ping

# Init script
COPY ./docker/docker-run.sh /docker-run.sh



VOLUME ["/var/www/html"]
EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["/bin/bash", "docker-run.sh"]
```